# Pairwise independence, mutual dependence

Tags: probability, independence

Joint density of random vector $(X,Y,Z)$ is given:

$f(x,y,z)=0.125·(1+xyz)$, where x,y,z $\in (-1,1)$

> My task is to prove that they are pairwise independent, but mutually dependent.

My solution:

For mutual independency we have to show that:

$f(x,y,z) \neq f(x)f(y)f(z)$

which is easy because: $0.125·(1+xyz) \neq 0.125$

For pairwise independency I have to show that:

$f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$

But I do not know how to do it.

I tried to put $z=0$, so I got following equation:

$f(x,y,0)=0.125·(1+xy0)=0.125$

$f(x)=0.5$

$f(y)=0.5$

but $0.125 \neq 0.25$

Can anyone help how to prove pairwise dependency?

Comment: $f(x,y,z)=0.125·(1+xyz)$ for which values of $x,y,z$?

Comment: @Darsen I updated my post, x,y,z $\in (-1,1)$

Comment: That can't be right, because the $f(x,y,z)$ wouldn't be a density function, since its integral over $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$ is 0.5.

Comment: @Darsen it is, it is written in the book like this

Comment: You're right. I messed up my calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to obtain the marginal density functions $f(x),f(y),f(z)$. This is done integrating respect to the other two variables respectively.

$f(x)=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}f(x,y,z)\,\text{d}y\text{d}z=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}0.125·(1+xyz)\,\text{d}y\text{d}z=\\0.125·\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}1\,\text{d}y\text{d}z+0.125·x\int_{-1}^{1}z\int_{-1}^{1}y\,\text{d}y\text{d}z=0.5\qquad\forall x\in(-1,1)$

Similarly $f(y)=0.5\quad\forall y\in(-1,1)$ and $f(z)=0.5\quad\forall z\in(-1,1)$.

Then clearly we don't have $f(x,y,z)=f(x)f(y)f(z)\quad\text{for almost every}\quad x,y,z\in(-1,1)^3$.

Now we have to obtain the not so marginal functions $f(x,y),f(x,z),f(y,z)$ integrating respect to the missing variable respectively (I don't know if those functions are given a name).

$f(x,y)=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{-1}f(x,y,z)\,\text{d}z=0.125·\int_{-1}^{-1}(1+xyz)\,\text{d}z=0.25\qquad\forall x,y\in(-1,1)^2$.

Similarly $f(x,z)=0.25\quad\forall x,z\in(-1,1)^2$ and $f(y,z)=0.25\quad\forall y,z\in(-1,1)^2$.

Then

$f(x,y)=0.25=0.5·0.5=f(x)f(y)\quad\forall x,y\in(-1,1)^2,
\\f(x,z)=0.25=0.5·0.5=f(x)f(z)\quad\forall x,z\in(-1,1)^2,\\
f(y,z)=0.25=0.5·0.5=f(y)f(z)\quad\forall y,z\in(-1,1)^2.$

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand it